# Firebase on Android, query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not call ValueEventListener even once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch a bunch of objects that satisfied a simple filter, but my ValueEventListener is not called even once.

My objects are like this:

```
trips/
  some-id-1/{creator="abc", other_field...}
  some-id-2/{creator="def" ...}
  ...
```

In an activity's onResume method, the app shows a progress dialog and fetches some objects, then upon the objects are fetched, the hides the progress dialog

In onResume, I do:

```
Query query  = mDatabaseReference.child("trips")
            .orderByChild("creator")
            .equalTo("xxx");

Log.d(TAG, "before fetch");
fetch(query);
Log.d(TAG, "after fetch");
```

fetch has the following implementation:

```
fetch(Query query) {
  ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          Log.i("data changed...")
          // hide the progress dialog...
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.i("cancelled...")
          // hide the progress dialog...
      }
  };
  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

While "before fetch" and "after fetch" are logged, neither "data changed" or "cancelled..." are logged, so ValueEventListener is not being fired. I never call the goOffline method and my phone has network for sure. Any reasons that the ValueEventListener not fired in my case?

Comment: Data retrieval from the Firebase Database happens asynchronously. So even if it does work, the `data changed...` or `cancelled...` messages will be way later in your logcat output.

Comment: I have waited for minutes and it never came...(filtering the logcat is easy to do and i did)

Comment: The recent cases of this behavior I remember were due to the device not being connected to the network. If your device is connected, you might want to turn on Firebase debug logging (`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)`) to see if there are any clues.

Comment: I cannot get my app to work properly at all. Firebase hangs the application very often and I notice there is always a message in the log when the hanging happens:  W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: Can you create a minimal app (e.g. in a github repo) that would allow me to reproduce the problem locally? That'll probably be easier to troubleshoot with.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found out the problem. I wrongly blocked the ValueEventListener.onDataChanged method. It's a bit hard to implement the tradition "find all employees which belong to the department X" in firebase because I have to fetch all employee IDs from the department X, then fetch employee one by one. I made a mistake when trying to gather all employees at once (firebase gives me one employee at a time, so I have to workaround this a bit).